# Read lines from a file and skip to next line if pattern matches in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read lines from a file and write the output to another file. I am using open to achieve this. But I am not able to weed out some unwanted lines from the first file.
here's the issue:

I have a text file with the following lines

```
Project1_Employees
Matt Stone
Trey parker
Eric Cartman
Kenny

Project2_Employees
Stan
Matt Stone
Trey Parker
Kyle
```

I am using my code to sort the names and print the uniq names. But I am not able to remove the lines Project1_Employees and Project2_Employees. This is only a part of the text file. There are hundreds of such lines.

```
open(FH, '<employeenames.txt');
next if (<FH> =~ m/Employees/);
open(OFH, ">sortedemployee.txt");
my %seen;
print OFH sort grep !$seen{$_}++, <FH>;
close(OFH);
close(FH);
```

The output I am looking for is

```
Eric Cartman
Kenny
Kyle
Matt Stone
Stan
Trey parker
```

I would like to do this using open as I have a requirement.

Comment: This would be incredibly easy in a shell, if can switch.

Comment: @BroSlow `uniq` would require sorted input

Comment: @mpapec Right, and it's trivial to sort. e.g. `grep -v '_Employees\|^$' file | sort -f | uniq -i` does pretty much exactly what OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(FH,  '<', 'employeenames.txt') or die $!;
open(OFH, '>', "sortedemployee.txt") or die $!;
my %seen;
print OFH sort grep { !$seen{$_}++ and !/Employees/ } <FH>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you understand much easier for this process.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub write_special_line {
    open my $file_handler, '<', 'test_file' or die;
    open my $new_handler, '>', 'write_test' or die;
    my $sign;
    my ($hash, @names);
    while (my $row = <$file_handler>) {
        if ($row =~ /Project\d+_Employees/) {
            next;
        } else {
            $hash->{$row} += 1;
            if ($hash->{$row} <= 1) {
                push @names, $row;
            }
        }
    }
    close $file_handler;
    my @sorted = sort {lc($a) cmp lc($b)} @names;
    for my $name (@sorted) {
        print $new_handler $name;
    }
    close $new_handler;
}

write_special_line();
```

Answer (score 0):

Already some good perl answers, but if you're not just practacing your `perl`, I wouldn't use `perl` just to do a simple file operation. Use something like gnu `grep`, e.g.

```
$ grep -v '_Employees\|^$' employeenames.txt | sort -f | uniq -i > sortedemployee.txt
$ cat sortedemployee.txt
Eric Cartman
Kenny
Kyle
Matt Stone
Stan
Trey parker
```